# Unable to load ApplicationContext for tests only because of org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration validator auto wiring

Tags: spring, testing, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to do some tests on my controller and I have got this weird error when launching the test.
The astonishing part is that I have exactly the same configurations for "production" and it is working nicely.
What I want to achieve is to set up an environment for my test on my controllers and I am starting with a simple one but apparently it is not that simple..

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:94)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:170)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:110)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:200)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:259)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:219)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'friendshipService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.mbpmx.repositories.FriendshipRepository fr.mbpmx.services.FriendshipService.friendshipRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'friendshipRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.validation.Validator org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.validator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#1
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:133)
at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private fr.mbpmx.repositories.FriendshipRepository fr.mbpmx.services.FriendshipService.friendshipRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'friendshipRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.validation.Validator org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.validator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#1
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 47 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'friendshipRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'neo4jTemplate' while setting bean property 'neo4jTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.validation.Validator org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.validator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#1
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1469)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.validation.Validator org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.validator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#1
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1111)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1006)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
... 62 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.validation.Validator org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.validator; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#1
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
... 79 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#1
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1054)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
... 81 more
```

This is my controller:

```
@RunWith( SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class )
@ContextConfiguration( locations = { "classpath:META-INF/integration-test-context.xml", "classpath:META-INF/dispatcher-test.xml" } )
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
public class HomeControllerTest {

    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private Neo4jTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Rollback(false)
    @BeforeTransaction
    public void cleanUpGraph() {
        Neo4jHelper.cleanDb( template );
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup( webApplicationContext ).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testLandingPage() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform( get( "/home" ) ).andExpect( status().isOk() );
    }

}
```

My integration-test-context.xml (not sure if it is an integration testing but anyway)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.mbpmx.domain" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.mbpmx.repositories" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.mbpmx.services" />

    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/neo4j-db-plain-test" base-package="fr.mbpmx.domain" />
    <neo4j:repositories base-package="fr.mbpmx.repositories" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <tx:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

And my dispatcher-test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.mbpmx.controller" />
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Finally, here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>fr.mbpmx</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring-Neo4j-Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Spring-Neo4j-Test</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.data.neo4j.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.data.neo4j.version>

        <neo4j-kernel.version>2.1.7</neo4j-kernel.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.10</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- JavaEE web profile -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging Related dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson dependencies for entities to JSON mapping -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test frameworks -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-kernel.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>social-network</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

Anybody has an idea?
You can find the sources of my small and humble project on [GitHub](https://github.com/evermax/spring-neo4j-test).
Thank you very much in advance for your answers!

Comment: There's two beans of the same type (Validator), so Spring doesn't know which one to wire and fails. Please try to find out where the two Validator bean definitions come from and get rid of one of them.

Comment: `No qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#1` make sure that you define a validator bean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is clear

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.validation.Validator] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.OptionalValidatorFactoryBean#1`

As others pointed out there are two validators (to be more precise validator factory beans) and Spring can't decide which one to use to autowire Validator into `Neo4jConfiguration` class.

This is most likely caused by having

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

twice in both **dispatcher-test.xml** file and **integration-test-context.xml**.

Remove one of the two and the error should disappear.

See [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable) for details of what mvc:annotation-driven does.

Comment: At first I thought it was something like that so I remove the 
    <mvc:annotation-driven> from the context configuration 
but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you push non-working branch into the git repo you have? I tried to add the two xml files to PersonRepositoryTest, which reproduced the issue.  Then removing the <mvc:annotation-driven> fixed that...

Comment: I pushed the working code with the annotation mvc:annotation-driven twice and if I build, the tests are working fine, because I added the validation bean.
But, Indeed, if I remove the bean and remove the mvc:annotation-driven from the context and kept it in the dispatcher, it works.

Comment: I still would like to understand why when I added the validator it works, I am gonna dig into that! Anyway, I pushed the code with the right modifications, meaning removing one of the mcv:annotation-driven AND the bean validator, thanks again!

Comment: You need the validator only when you want to use bean validation (JSR-303) - http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#reference_programming-model_validation , otherwise you can skip that. If you really want to understand what Spring is doing try adding this to your log4j file log4j.logger.org.springframework=DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you comment [Michel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/728812/michael-hunger).

I added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

to the pom.xml and:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

to the context file.

I have to admit that I didn't knew that I was needing it. And it feels weird because I when I run tests on the repositories without the validator it was working fine.
So why having a problem when testing the controller and not the repositories?

Is it the right call to use Hibernate Validator whereas I don't use Hibernate anywhere else?

Sorry for those rookie questions, but I feel like I spotted a hole in my knowledge of Spring and I would like to understand a bit more about what happens here.

Comment: I feel like this is not the right answer in fact, but I keep it here anyway for future reference, in case I found something to explain why it worked!